# How can I login to MySQL via C++ code using xdevapi?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am trying to login to MySQL via C++ code using building connector c++, here is my code with my password removed:

std::string url = "mysqlx://localhost:3306/license_db?user=licuser&password=**********";

Session mySession(url);

mySession.sql("use license_db").execute();

auto result = mySession.sql("SELECT * FROM product").execute();

Row row1 = result.fetchOne();

The code causes an exception on the "Session mySession(url);" line and the exception says "bad allocation".

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

The URI is usally **mysqlx://user:password@host:3306/schema** for X DevAPI, whih works for JS, PHP, and Python.

There is an example at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/database-connection-example.html for C++

var mySession = MySQLX.GetSession("server=localhost;port=33060;user=user;password=password;");

Comment: That very page gives an example of a connection URI like the OP uses.

Comment: Furthermore what does this have to do with allocation?

Comment: Thanks for the help but it hasn't worked yet. But why is this different?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/using-sql.html

Comment: Seems like the documentation is wrong. Dave is right, the DevAPI format should be common for all the official connectors (I have not tried C++ specifically tho) but I know for a fact it works with the Node.js connector (I'm the lead maintainer of the project).

Comment: In the end that answer did work but there were loads of other computer and VS project issues.